# Multiple child_processes are created in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

I have this node js code

```
var bat = null;
app.post("/api/run", function(req,res) {
    if(!bat) {
        bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c App.exe']);
    }

    if(req.body.success) {
        bat.kill();
    }

    bat.stdin.write(req.body.input+'\n');

    bat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
      res.end(JSON.stringify({data: data.toString()}));
    });

    bat.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    bat.on('exit', function (code) {
      bat = null;
      console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
    });    
});
```

This code is suppose to create only one child process that will run exe file. But after 3 ajax request when child process is kill this is output on console:

`Input NO: 1 You entered: input 1`

`Input NO: 2 You entered: input 2`

`Input NO: 2 You entered: input 2`

`Input NO: 3 You entered: input 3`

`Input NO: 3 You entered: input 3`

`Input NO: 3 You entered: input 3`

`Child exited with code 1`
`Child exited with code 1`
`Child exited with code 1`

while it should log each input one time and there should be only one child process. What is wrong with this code.
Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only instantiating one process but your continually hooking up new event handlers on every request which is why you get duplicate output (3 requests = 3x the message).

Move your `.on` calls inside the `if (!bat)` statement

```
if (!bat) {
    bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c App.exe']);
    bat.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.end(JSON.stringify({data: data.toString()}));
    });
    bat.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    bat.on('exit', function (code) {
        bat = null;
        console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
    });
}
bat.stdin.write(req.body.input+'\n');
```

Comment: @SaadMehmood not all heroes ware capes

Answer (score 1):

There is only one child process actually, but every request will add an `exit` event listener for the child process. So the second time input display twice and the third time display 3 times. And display `Child exited` 3 times.

You could try following ways.

- add event listener at the time of child process be created
- remove the listener after response sent
- use `once` to set a one time listener for those event

Hope this can help you